# loading image in jquery on wordpress

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

I am converting my HTML website to a WordPress theme, and I couldn't load the image from the folder. I used jQuery to load the images. It works in my normal HTML template but not in WordPress. Any tips?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#view3608").tikslus360({
    imageDir: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/one/',
    imageCount: 36,
    imageExt: 'png',
    canvasID: 'mycar',
    canvasWidth: 468,
    canvasHeight: 813,
    autoRotate: false
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. There's a lot of reasons this may not be working; jQuery not loaded correctly, wrong image path etc.

Comment: Where are you putting this code?